# jsPlumb - deleteEveryEndpoint + detachAllConnections

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb and I'm having some problems with deleteEveryEndpoint and detachAllConnections.
I have a "Clear All" button to clear everything and my code for that button is:

```
$('#clearAll').click(function(e) {
    instance.deleteEveryEndpoint();
    $('.w').each(function() {
        instance.detachAllConnections($(this)[0].id);
        $(this).remove();
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
    instance.repaintEverything();
});
```

where $('.w') are my divs.

This clears everything but if, after I click this button, I draw 2 items (one source and one target) and create a connection between them, this new connection will appear in a place where there was a connection before I clicked the button.

Original diagram:
[image]

After clicking "Clear All" button and drawing a source, a target and a connection between them:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to remove the "e.stopPropagation()" and the "instance.repaintEverything();" but nothing seems to work.

Thank you.